# Python - is it possible (and recommendable) to have requirements.txt and setup.py in different folders (hierarchies)?

Tags: python

I have my python project in this structure:

```
base->
    Project->
           libs (dir)
           model (dir)
           testing (dir)
           views (dir)
           main.py
           requirements.txt
           settings.py
```

Now I would like to create a `setup.py` for building packages.
As I read I should create it at one level above so that is within the `base` folder if I am not mistaken.

Also I need to create `__init__.py` file as well.
I think that file should be created in `Project` folder.

Since I already have requirements.txt
is it OK to have setup.py and requirements.txt file in different hierarchies and to set the full path in `with open` method of the `setup.py` script?
Reason why I can't move the requirements.txt file in same hierarchy is because:

1. I got project that I am not allowed to modify (regarding the position of the current files)
2. setup.py must be at one level above.

Is that OK to have them at different hierarchies? I know they should be at the same level, at least that is what I saw in examples as recommendable..

```
with open('Project/requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

...

setup(
    name='package name',
    version='version',
    install_requires=requirements,
    ...
)
```